# How to concatenate portions of df to another df

Tags: pandas, concatenation

I have a df like this: df1
[image]

And i have another df like this: df2

[image]

I want to concatenate all rows of df2 that have the same CODIGO with df1. Rows of df2 must be below df1 like this:

[image]

All values must be concatenated with their respective column. I will appreciate any help.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pd.concat for this.
The axis will be 0, or default, you don't need specify it.
You need order, use sort for this,

> result = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort=True)

You can use Dataframe.append.

> result = df1.append(df4, ignore_index=True, sort=True)

Looks like indexes and order of the columns are different between your dataframes, you need to re-arrange this, and ideally have a meaningful unique index CODIGO_AñO_MES_DIA to do a proper sorting.

Be aware that sorting is alphabetical.